# Signals not handled in Linux kernel init thread

Tags: linux-kernel, signals

I have the following problem with Linux kernel: When a signal (exception) is occurred in the init thread, where kernel is loading drivers, that signal is not handled in any way, causing the system to freeze. It is even not possible to use debugger.

However, when same signal is raised on a user process after the kernel is booted, it is caught and does not cause the system freeze:

```
# devmem2 0x51002104 w
/dev/mem opened.[  206.043479] 8<--- cut here ---
[  206.047808] Unhandled fault: asynchronous external abort (0x1211) at 0x00000000    
[  206.055149] pgd = b7e0d3b2
[  206.057865] [00000000] *pgd=a8fc7003, *pmd=00000000

Memory mapped at address 0xb6f2d000.
Bus error
```

In the pcie-keystone.c driver, there is following signal handler:

```
#ifdef CONFIG_ARM
    /*
     * PCIe access errors that result into OCP errors are caught by ARM as
     * "External aborts"
     */
    hook_fault_code(17, ks_pcie_fault, SIGBUS, 0,
            "Asynchronous external abort");
#endif
```

Setting similar handler in my code does not help. When the driver is loaded as a module after the init process is done, the signal does not freeze the system too.

Could a Linux kernel expert advise, is there a hidden option in the kernel config? Or the platform initialization has missing piece, so that the init thread is not fully configured and unable to handle signals? I am on ARM AM5728 machine.

Comment: If there is an error on kernel, we need to know it, and panic. No operation will be safe. So correct the driver. Note: exceptions are not signals (kernel can send signal to processes, but usually just for clean exit, but killing init is not good. PID=1 has special signal handling (see man pages about signals). So fix the driver!

Comment: Unfortunately the situation is that this exception depends on presence of the external PCIe 100MHz clock, which can be switched off on our board. There is no way to check if the clock exists or not in SW before reading - it is controlled externally. If the driver is used as module, the desired effect is achieved, but I am looking on how to fix this in a better way. The problem is that even kernel panic is not triggered, the system just freezes.
I am going to test the signal handling for PID=1 for different architectures/machines.

Comment: I really think you can correct things in the driver. In any case you repeatedly write "exception": could you provide more information? Which kind of exception. You must know it precisely, in order to handle it (and as I say, you can do it in kernel). Linux born in a epoch where one should prove I/O ports and memory to detect also the most simple hardware. It seems you are looking the wrong work-around. Try to reframe the problem. Ask a co-worker (often it is enough to ask, and you find the solution yourself, but there is no shortcut)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I returned back to this problem some time ago. The root cause was that under some conditions, no any ARM exceptions are thrown, the hardware just freezes the memory bus and CPU.

I reworked the pipe3 PCIe PHY driver, so that it checks if APLL is locked before letting the PCIe core to start initializing. This is mentioned in the AM57x TRM but not implemented in the mainline Linux driver. Maybe will send patches later to LKML...

The problem is very similar to this: https://e2e.ti.com/support/processors-group/processors/f/processors-forum/615543/am5728-pcie-access-hangs-dsp-and-arm

The reason why behavior is different in init thread and on running system is runtime power management, which disables the PCIe core clock after the kernel is loaded.